# neo4j-shell Network is unreachale

Tags: neo4j

Trying to follow the tutorial in the book "Learning Neo4j". I'm stuck in the section where it describes how to use the neo4j shell to import data.

When I try to run the shell from my Macbook I get this error:

```
$ neo4j-shell -v
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
    Exception creating connection to: 192.168.227.149; nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 192.168.227.149; nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
```

.... many more lines of stack trace.

I don't recognize the 192.168 address. As far as I can tell that is not my local network IP address.

Neo4j was installed via homebrew.

I've also tried explicitly setting the host and port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably has nothing to do with neo4j.  The `192.168.*.*` network is a reserved IP space for your local network.   The message "network unreachable" usually means that you have a networking problem much lower in the stack; like your ethernet cable is unplugged, you're not connected to a wireless network, or whatever the case may be.

But what neo4j is saying here is that you're trying to connect to something remote, and your machine overall doesn't have a network connection or you have some kind of firewall set up that is not permitting any traffic back and forth.

Your fix should be to check your OS networking settings, or talk to someone locally who configures such things.  Do you have any relevant environment information?   E.g. did you [edit your conf/neo4j.properties](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/shell-starting.html) in any way?  Normally, the shell should bail out and tell you to specify where to connect when you call it without any arguments like that, so I'm betting you did customize something.

If your intent is to connect to a local file database, then you might be better off doing something like this:

```
$ neo4j-shell -file my-local-database.db
```